# Terminal object in $Set^{C^{op}}$ and subobject classifier.

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory

This is from Sheaves in Geometry and Logic pg 38.

I'm not sure if I understood it correctly but the subobject classifier in  $Set^{C^{op}}$ when $C$ is a small category is a map (natural transformation) which sends every object $D$ to the maximal sieve on $D$

so we've got $ true : 1 \implies \Omega$ .

What is $1$ in this category? I thought if $C^{op}$ has a terminal object $1_{c^{op}}$ then  i could consider $Y(1_{^{op}})$ but i have no idea.

Comment: $1$ is the constant functor $C^{op}\to Set$ sending every object to $1$.

Comment: Ok  then : $true_C : \{ * \} \rightarrow \Omega(C)$ sending the singleton to the maximal sieve on C. Am I right?

Comment: I don't recall what true is for this category (or I would have posted an answer :) ,) but that would be my guess.

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Why are answers posted as comments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The terminal object is in fact the constant functor to a fixed one-point set. This can be seen from the fact that the value $F(C)$ at any object $C\in\mathscr{C}$ has a unique map to the terminal object in $\mathbf{Sets}$, and obviously the terminal object restricts along all morphisms in $\mathscr{C}$. $\Omega (C)$ returns the collection of all sieves on $C$ (or in a sheaf category - the collection of all $J$-closed sieves - sieves which contain every object that they $J$-cover).

Truth then corresponds to the natural transformation taking each $\{*\}$ to the maximal element of $\Omega (C)$. This corresponds to the fact that the section in question lives on ``all of $C$''. In general, for a given section on $F\in \text{Sh}(\mathscr{C})$ at $C$, the truth value associated with that section corresponding with a subsheaf $G$ will be the largest closed sieve on $C$ such that the section lives on the whole region specified by the sieve in $G$. In the extreme case, when it is on all of $C$, this will be the maximal sieve corresponding to $C$ itself (if you want to think in terms of a fixed site).

Comment: It's been a long since i posted this question but this kind of nice answers are always welcomed !